# Is the ellipsis behind 'such as' grammatically correct?

Tags: etymology, ellipsis

> [[OED]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/193400?rskey=S7S02U&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) 7.  a. With correlative *as* pron. (see [AS conj. 17](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/11307#eid38320125)),
>   Middle English also *as that*, taking the place of Old English *swelce, swá*.
>   ***such as*** = Of the kind or degree that; the kind of (person or thing) that.
>   [...]  [Examples without ellipsis]  ***ellipt.***  [Examples with ellipsis]
>
> **My guesses on what was ellipted:** 2.1. No other X ebb, than such as ebbs.
>   ¿=>? 2.3.  No other X ebb, than such **[X]** as **[that/which]** ebbs.
>
> 3.1. Such as do X, will do Y.
>   ¿=>? 3.3. Such **[people/thing]** as **[that/who]**  do X, will do Y.

All ellipses [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29) ellipt only what was explicitly written at least once (ie: the antecedents). Per contra, no explicit antecedents exist for all ellipted 
in '**such as**', which I bolded in my guesses above (ie: the nouns **[X]** and **[people/thing]** and the relative pronouns **[that/which/who]**)?

1. I can't pinpoint why, but this ellipsis appears extravagant and wrong, because it  makes **such as** seem mutilated and deficient. 
   Is this type of ellipsis special?
   Would someone please explain or naturalise it?
2. What were the precise steps or processes behind the ellipsis of 'such as'?

Comment: The verb is _elide_.

Comment: It’s confusing when you talk about language with terms like ‘extravagant, wrong, mutilated, deficient’; do you just mean unreasonable or hard to imagine?

Comment: @JeremyNeedle Yes, thanks. Please feel free to edit my OP. I wished to emphasise the unreasonableness; so my diction might have sounded unreasonable.